# Return value of SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, windows, sqlcmd

I need to check the exit status (success/failure) of a query run through SQLCMD utility. For example, the server I am connecting *doesn't* have a database name `EastWind`. Then, the command below fails with the message ...

```
> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" 
     -S ZEPHIR -E -Q "USE WestWind"
Changed database context to 'WestWind'.
> echo %errorlevel%
0
> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" 
     -S ZEPHIR -E -Q "USE EastWind"
Database 'EastWind' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly
> echo %errorlevel%
0
```

I see that the return value is the same in both the cases. How can I check if a command has failed in `SQLCMD`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to use the [`-V` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)

> *Note:* That's a capital `-V`, not a lowercase `-v`.

Example:

```
> SQLCMD.EXE -S whatever -E -V16 -Q "USE does_not_exist"
  Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, ...
  Could not locate entry ...
> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
  16
```

**Update:** Alternatively, you can use the `-b` option, which has different semantics to the execution (the whole batch stops on the first error). YMMV.

Example:

```
> SQLCMD.EXE -S whatever -E -b -Q "USE does_not_exist"
  Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, ...
  Could not locate entry ...
> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
  1
```

You can also combine `-b` and `-V`.

Comment: Thanks Christian. Together all the three error reporting options `-m, -V,` and `-b` give good solution to my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure, but did you tried SQLCMD -m switch? [sqlcmd Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)

> `-m error_level` - Controls which error messages are sent to stdout. Messages that have a severity level greater than or equal to this level are sent. When this value is set to `-1`, all messages including informational messages, are sent. Spaces are not allowed between the `-m` and `-1`. For example, `-m-1` is valid, and `-m -1` is not.