# Accessing the returned value of a SQL statement in SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, dos, sqlcmd

I'm trying to get the value of a SQL statement when I run it in a DOS batch file ...

```
sqlcmd -E -S DEVSERVER -Q "SELECT  COUNT(1) as [CaseCount] FROM Cases"
```

I'm not after the error level as in this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418690/return-value-of-sqlcmd) question, rather I'm after the actual count returned from the database, so I can do some additional logic.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can easily save the result of the execution into a text file, either by using the `-o` sqlcmd flag or by using the standard `>` redirector. You can then format this file by removing the column header (flag `-h`) and removing the rowcount from SQL Server (`SET NOCOUNT ON`).

The following script will generate a file `result.txt` with only the value of `COUNT(1)` and a line break:

```
SQLCMD -E -S devserver -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Cases" -h -1 
  > result.txt
```

And then read the value back with ...

```
set /p value=< result.txt
echo %value%
```

Comment: +1 Just saw, after posting my answer that your's also includes the `-h -1` option.

Comment: Partly ... how do I get the value back into the DOS batch file ?

Comment: Then maybe @Christian.K solution (using FOR) might suits you better, since it will evaluate the result of the command and then you can assign to a batch variable, you only have to add a simple test to avoid the empty string.

Comment: I've tracked down a solution and added to your post ... thanks for the response

Comment: reading the value from the file with `set /p value=<result.txt` is great.

Answer (score 19):

You can avoid an extra/temporary file, by calling `sqlcmd.exe` using the `FOR` batch command:

```
for /F usebackq %%i in (`sqlcmd -E -S "devserver,4711" -h-1 -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT COUNT(1) ..."`) do (
    set count=%%i
)

if not defined count (
    echo Failed to execute SQL statement 1>&2
) else (
    echo %count%
)
```

Some notes:

- If called from an interactive `CMD.EXE` session, i.e. the command line, use `%i` instead of `%%i`
- The `-h-1` option tells `sqlcmd.exe` to suppress the column headers, so the output is really only one line of text.
- I used a fictional port 4711 with the server, to show that you need to put the whole "server,port" specification in double quotes. Otherwise, due to CMD's command line parsing rules, `sqlcmd` would see server and port as to distinct arguments and fail.

Comment: Sometimes, there might be leading or trailing spaces in the result so you might want to use `for /F "delims= " %%i...` instead. Do note that this deletes *all* spaces including the ones in between so be careful.

Comment: @Mark OK, I see. In that case it might be better to trim the spaces off the `count` variable, after the `for` look: `set count=%count: =%`.

Answer (score 4):

The answer from @GerardoLima was 90% of the way there. You additionally need to evaluate the input value with `set /a` to strip the leading whitespace.

This is not required with the answer from @Christian.K

```
SQLCMD -E -S devserver -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Cases" -h -1 > result.txt
set /p raw=< result.txt
echo '%raw%'
set /a value=%raw%
echo '%value%'
```

My output was

```
'          0'
'0'
```