# Using a batch file to call sequential SQL Agent jobs, but how do I end the process if one of the jobs fails?

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sql-agent-job

I'm using a batch file to call sequential SQL Agent jobs. That part works fine, but my current challenge is that I need to **stop** the process when one of the SQL Agent jobs fails.

**Business Requirement:**

Step 1: Call SQLAgentJob1 to run on DBServer. If SQLAgentJob1 fails, this batch script should exit (not call other steps). If SQLAgentJob1 succeeds, call SQLAgentJob2.

Step 2: Call SQLAgentJob2 to run on DBServer. If SQLAgentJob2 fails, this batch script should exit (not call other steps). If SQLAgentJob2 succeeds, call the RunMe.cmd.

Step 3: Call RunMe.cmd to run on WebServer

Step 4: Call SQLAgentJob3 to run on DBServer. If SQLAgentJob3 fails, this batch script should exit. If SQLAgentJob3 succeeds, this batch script should exit.

**Current Status**

I have used the batch file to successfully call each of the SQL Agent jobs and the command line task, but I'm stuck on trying to STOP the process if any one of the SQLAgentJobs fail. Right now, even if SQLAgentJob1 fails, the batch file still calls SQLAgentJob2.

Here is the scripting as it currently stands:

```
ECHO starting SQLAgentJob1
sqlcmd -S DBServer -E -d MSDB -Q "sp_start_job 'SQLAgentJob1'"


ECHO starting the SQL job
sqlcmd -S DBServer -E -d MSDB -Q "sp_start_job 'SQLAgentJob2'"
ECHO OFF
ECHO.

set CMDDIR = D:\webapps
pushd CMDDIR
call RunMe.cmd
popd

ECHO starting SQLAgentJob1
sqlcmd -S DBServer -E -d MSDB -Q "sp_start_job 'SQLAgentJob3'"
```

Also, very challengingly, even when the SQL Agent Job fails, the %errorlevel% that is returned as part of the batch file for that job is 0 (not 1).

Any ideas/suggestions? Ideal world I'd like to continue using the batch scripting (in part because SQL isn't installed on my webserver, and I need to call the .cmd from my webserver and also run the SQL Agent jobs), although if it's impossible or too difficult, I can change to something else.

Thanks in advance for any help and forgive me if I've used any terminology incorrectly.

Comment: How to know, if it fails or succeeds? Is there a specific output or better: is there an %errorlevel%?

Comment: Good question. I don't know how to set up specific output on the SQL Agent job in a way that my batch script will recognize (and didn't see anything that looked likely while poking around it). 

When the SQL Agent job fails, it currently sends out an e-mail to me, but that's obviously not something the batch file can catch. I do have the option to set alerts of 'SQL Server event alert', 'sql Server performance condition alert', and 'WMI event alert' and to send errors by e-mail, pager, and net send.

Comment: Hm - nothing of that seems to be helpful. But I'm sure they implemented a way to check the status from command line. First try to use %errorlevel%. Put `echo %errorlevel`% in the line after a `sqlcmd` you know will fail. If it is not equal `0`, the rest will be easy.

Comment: take a look to @Mofi s answer, that looks very promising.

Comment: I took your suggestion to try reading the %errorlevel% after a sqlcmd that was set up to fail. Unfortunately, it showed 0 :(

Comment: not good. Plan B: How do you know, that it failed? Any text output to the console?

Answer (score 0):

I found with a simple search [Return value of SQLCMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418690/return-value-of-sqlcmd).

The problem should be (not tested) easily solved using `-b` parameter on `sqlcmd`.

```
ECHO starting SQLAgentJob1
sqlcmd -S DBServer -E -d MSDB -b -Q "sp_start_job 'SQLAgentJob1'"
if errolevel 1 exit /b

ECHO starting the SQL job
sqlcmd -S DBServer -E -d MSDB -b -Q "sp_start_job 'SQLAgentJob2'"
if errorlevel 1 goto :EOF
ECHO OFF
ECHO.

set CMDDIR = D:\webapps
pushd CMDDIR
call RunMe.cmd
popd

ECHO starting SQLAgentJob1
sqlcmd -S DBServer -E -d MSDB -Q "sp_start_job 'SQLAgentJob3'"
```

Or you use `-V X` option additionally to `-b` to exit the batch file if an error of level `X` specified on usage of `-V` occurs.

```
ECHO starting SQLAgentJob1
sqlcmd -S DBServer -E -d MSDB -V 11 -b -Q "sp_start_job 'SQLAgentJob1'"
if errolevel 1 exit /b

ECHO starting the SQL job
sqlcmd -S DBServer -E -d MSDB -V 11 -b -Q "sp_start_job 'SQLAgentJob2'"
if errolevel 1 goto :EOF
ECHO OFF
ECHO.

set CMDDIR = D:\webapps
pushd CMDDIR
call RunMe.cmd
popd

ECHO starting SQLAgentJob1
sqlcmd -S DBServer -E -d MSDB -Q "sp_start_job 'SQLAgentJob3'"
```

Please let us know what works best and I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the link, btw. I did try the following, setting up SQLAgentJob1 to fail:

sqlcmd -S DBServer -E -b -V1 -d MSDB -Q "sp_start_job 'SQLAgentJob1'"
if errorlevel 1 goto :EOF

I also tried if errorlevel 1 goto exit /b

Unfortunately, the second SQLAgentJob ran both times. (I also tried with just -V1 and with just -b, but neither worked).

Comment: What about using `sqlcmd -S DBServer -E -b -V 11 -r -d MSDB -Q "sp_start_job 'SQLAgentJob1'"2>"%TEMP%\SqlError.txt"` and what does the file "%TEMP%\SqlError.txt" contain after execution of sqlcmd which fails because of an error? If there is really an error message written with using option `-r` to **stderr** redirected into the file on fail, but not on successful execution, the batch file could check file size of SqlError.txt after running sqlcmd. With a file size of 0 bytes, no error occurred, otherwise exit batch job because of an error.

Comment: So I wasn't sure how to implement your suggestion above. But I did create a sproc that would run from a local .sql file immediately after each job ran; the sproc would review the SQL Agent Job History to see if the job succeeded. If the job did not succeed, the sproc would raise a custom error (which the batch file recognized, successfully exiting the process). But now it looks like the Jobs don't wait for each other to complete! The sproc is sometimes too fast to run; if the sproc starts before the job finishes, it doesn't work right. A ping can force accurate results, but not good long term.

Comment: What type of error do you want to detect at all? Server is not reachable? SQL service not running on server? Database locked? Query itself fails? Before we can detect errors by batch commands, we need to know what errors occur and which errorlevels are returned by `sqlcmd` on those errors.